# Excel read-only and Microsoft Query/ADO Query

Tags: sql-server, excel, ado, vba

I developed an Excel 2007/2010 WorkBook which import data (returned by SqlServer stored procedures via VBA AND ADO) into several Excel Tables of a worksheet called “Data” of my WorkBook.
I then use ADO (the connection pointing the workbook itself) to retrieve the data in other worksheets. I like this ADO layer because it allows me to clearly separate the Data Access Layer (the Data Worksheet) and the application (all other worksheet). Pivot tables are not an option in my case because I need to add some formulas to the retrieved data. This is how I setup the connection string for my WorkBook

```
Private Function GetThisWorkbookCN() As String
   Dim fileFullPath As String
   fileFullPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
   GetThisWorkbookCN = "DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & fileFullPath  
End Function
```

My problem is that everything works fine as long as the workbook is not read-only: in this case the connection points to the saved workbook and not to the opened file.
Do you think is it possible to set up the connection in order to get the data form the opened file?
Currently, I’m forcing every user to save locally each version of the workbook, but I’d like to avoid this.

EDIT: Remou suggested, as a workaround, to save the data in a local file (csv or other formats) and use ADO to that file and not to the Workbook itself. This avoid the maintenance problem as the main file can be opened in read-only mode.

Comment: Why is the file read-only? Is it that you have multiple users accessing the same file? It is possible to allow multiple users access by sharing, as long as you do not have tables, but i am not sure how safe this will be. It depends on your environment.

Comment: yes, I have multiple users. I don't want to share the workbook: it is by its nature read-only: every change which has to be persisted and visible to other users it is saved in the sqlserver.

Comment: Maybe I gave too little information: each user sets some parameters, get the data from the sqlserver and the excel application transform those data in some way. There is no point for the user to save the workbook, as everything is recreated once the data are retreived (actually, the user can save some data, but not in the excel files, but in the sqlserver). For manteinance reason, I'd like to have just one excel file and don't let every user to save a local copy of the workbook

Comment: If the user is supplying input, have you considered a form?

Comment: BTW, ADO uses the data in the open workbook, not the saved version, though I have not tested with a read-only version.

Comment: What I experienced is that it uses data in the open workbook IF the file is open in read-write mode. If it is opened in read-only it doesn't. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, I can see that it does not work with a readonly version. I think you will have to use a form or read the cells entered using VBA. What exactly is the user supplying?

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean with form? I can't figure out how use a form in this context.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12448/discussion-between-remou-and-alev)

Comment: @AleV Just something to keep in mind when using ADO to connect to Excel: If you query an open workbook with ADO then you'll leak memory even after closing the connection and clearing the object. If you're going to query Excel workbooks with ADO you want to make sure that those workbooks are closed when running the query.

Comment: @Kittoes thanks, good point (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985580/using-adodb-to-access-opened-xls-file/9168482#9168482)