# Excel Sql throws Too few parameters error when Sql run in Excel read only mode

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have an excel sheet where i am loading data into "Data" Sheet from oracle through ODBC. and then applying excel sql to filter some data

Note: i am working on server machine so can not paste entire code. but whatever i put is 100% correct.

```
'Load Data Sheet
Sql = Select * from oracleTable
. . . 
set rs1 = commandData.Execute() 'record set
'Then code to store rs1 values in to Data Sheet...
.
.
'Apply filter in Excel 
query = select col1,col2,col3 from [Data$A1:IV100] where col1='10'
set rs = commandData.Execute() 'record set
```

which returns proper result when opened in write mode.
But, when i put the sheet in read only mode for my users to protect the content of the sheet. 
It works to load data from oracle then It shows error when i execute the filter excel sql at line.

```
   set rs = commandData.Execute() ' Error at this line when opened in read only mode
```

**Error:**

> [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1

Is it something like when the excel is opened in read only it opens in Temp directory , so while executing excel query , is it struggling to find correct sheet to apply sql ?

Comment: Please show __actual code__, not pseudo-code.  All I can tell from what you have there is you're not using `Set` when assigning `rs`

Comment: @TimWilliams : I modified my query. I am using Set. thats not the prob. It shows error.

Comment: @TimWilliams : My question is modified now very clearly. I can not copy paste entire code as i am working on server machine. and moreover i explained my problem very well as working in Write mode but not in Read only mode.

Comment: Logan I believe it will give an error if Excel is Read Only. Why? I am not sure. But the alternative is to save your workbook as CSV and then use the query to interact with the CSV.

Comment: You cannot do use ADO with a read-only file, as you are discovering. I might be able to suggest something if I knew more about what you are doing. For example, it may suit to write out your data to a csv : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992820/excel-read-only-and-microsoft-query-ado-query

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the .Execute() function correctly.

Syntax for non-row-returning:

```
commandobject.Execute RecordsAffected, Parameters, Options
```

Syntax for row-returning:

```
Set recordsetobject = commandobject.Execute (RecordsAffected, Parameters, Options)
```

Here's a link for more indepth coverage: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ado/quickref/command_execute.html

Comment: I am using set. Question updated correctly. it shows error. I said code is working in edit mode but not in read only mode

Answer (score 0):

I run into this error a lot myself. If you get hung up try this:

1. Open up the VBA editor
2. Press Ctrl + G (this will open up the Immediate Window)
3. Set a breakpoint in your code right after you have assigned the query to a variable (in this case the line right after `query =`
4. When the code breaks on your breakpoint, type `?query` in the Immediate Window and press Enter
5. This will write the SQL statement to the Immediate Window
6. Review the SQL Statement for any errors (missing quotes, etc.)

You can also try pasting the SQL statement from the Immediate Window into your database and run the query. Sometimes your database will throw a more specific error message and you can correct your VBA code accordingly.

Comment: After reading your edits to the question, I'm not sure that my answer is applicable