# How to change Excel Connection to stop the Read-Only Erro

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have 3 Source Excel files and one Master Excel file.

The master file has a connection to the 3 source files, and creates a Pivot Table from the data in the 3 files.

When a user opens the master file and updates the data, the 3 source files become "read-only".

I want to know some way to grab the data but then release the connection.

The connection string in the connections is:

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=Z:\Supply Chain Planning\Short Shipment Reports\RT- Shortage Report 2012.xls;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="HDR=YES;";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False

Comment: You can find some answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985580/using-adodb-to-access-opened-xls-file/9168482#9168482

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the `Mode` parameter from `Share Deny Write` to `Read`.