# Equivalent of Oracle Group By statement in ADODB to Excel?

Tags: excel, vbscript, ado, adodb

I have some data in Excel as below:

```
EmpId     Ename      joining Date      mangerid

12         aa            12/10             15
22         abc           11/10             15
42         ara           12/10             11
15         pp            08/10             10
12         bb            02/10             11
```

Now i can write a code in Oracle - to see how many employes are under the same manager and their names.But now I want the same using `ADO-DB` process.so how could i write a code for the same?

Oracle :

select mangerid,(select ename from employe where mangerid=e.manager id ),Count(4) from emp e group by mangerid

I have such data in my excel sheet.

**OUTPUT**

```
Mangerid      empid      count
================================
15            12           2
              22
11            12           2
              42
10            15           1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using ADO-DB"?  Oracle is a DBMS, ADO-DB is just an interface to a DBMS, which could include Oracle.  It's not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @RBarryYoung thanks for looking into my post! I know that what you meant. But I have an oracle table like data in my Excel sheet as descriped in my post.Now I want to do such oracle like operation using `ADODB` on my excel and get the output to another sheet of the same Excel!

Comment: It's relatively easy to do these kinds of things in Excel-VBA without ADODB, but if you're calling this from vbscript then ADODB may be a better way to go.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Can you help here by providing a demo code to get some knowledge about such ADODB?

Comment: The problem here is with your Oracle query and output.  I am not an Oracle expert, but this does not look like it is valid SQL (you should be getting a "multiple result" error on the subquery), and the "Output" does not look like valid SQL output in any DBMS that I know of.  I have added the "Oracle" tag in the hope that some Oracle expert will see this and can clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an MSDN article about [using ADO with Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819). The following code is modified slightly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985580/using-adodb-to-access-opened-xls-file). This queries `Sheet1` from `C:\example.xls`.  The data is then loaded into Modify as needed. This is a VBA example, and I don't have time to change it to VBS right now. It assumes you actually have Excel and have ADODB referenced.

```
Sub test()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sql As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\example.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
sql = "SELECT [manger id], Ename from [Sheet1$] Order by [manger id]"

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open sql, conn, 1

'Load data from recordset
Worksheets("Results").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I used Order By in the SQL query because I couldn't understand what you were returning with your Oracle query.

Comment: please see my output and tell me if the same can be be achieved via the `ADODB`?

Comment: I don't know. I couldn't get it to work because it wouldn't return empid unless I grouped by it, if I grouped by manager id. I'm not saying it is impossible though, because I don't know. Tinker with the SQL. In my experience I'd never seen a query like yours, but I have very limited Oracle exp. This simply shows you can do a SQL type query against your Excel workbook. It may make more sense to get your data and then modify it with VBScript.

Comment: can the output be produced with ADODB anyway?

Comment: may i have some help on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087196/is-there-any-oracle-equivalent-update-and-delete-command-in-adodb#comment19485936_14087196